# Create a C++ string with given format

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I'm a Objective-C dev and sometimes I have to deal with C/C++ code.
I have a function written in C++, it logs an event with name, for example, Level_12_Pack_10. I want to create a dynamic C++ string like that, then I can change level and pack numbers.
In Objective C, it's easy with some lines of code: [NSString stringwithformat] but in C++, it's a bit difficult for me.
Could anyone help me do it?

Comment: What you want is easy enough. Show us what you have tried. Look up std::string in the stl.  You might look for examples of ostream operator<< overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think C++ supports strings with built-in changeable variables like that. It would be too over-the-top to make a class to format the string like that. Probably the closest thing you can get is to use stringstreams:

```
#include <sstream>
string makeMyString(int level, int pack) {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << "Level_" << level << "_Pack_" << pack;
  return ss.str();
}
```

If you have a string that you need to read and change the values inside, a similar function could be used.

Answer (score 1):

With c++11, it is drop dead simple just use std::to_string(level) etc to concatenate strings.

```
int level = 10;
int pack = 40;

std::string stuff = "Level_" + std::to_string(level) + "_Pack_" + std::to_string(pack);
//stuff is now "Level_10_Pack_40"
std::cout << stuff;
```